# Placing CSS/ JS into the header or footer (inline) - trying to apply to several templates

Tags: functions, wp-head

The below code works perfectly well thanks to this help from a [previous question I posted.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276403/is-there-a-way-to-push-javascript-or-css-on-page-in-a-template-via-functions-p)

The code that I've posted directly below injects CSS (or JS) into the wp_head of WordPress....

My question is: how do I make this happen on several designated templates? I thought my code listed second on this question would have worked but it is wrong.

I would like to place some CSS/ JS on specific templates in the wp_head and wp_footer

```
function wpse_276403_output_scripts() {
    ?>
    <script>alert('Hello world!');</script>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #F00;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_276403_output_scripts' );
```

My attempt below failed to load CSS into 'page-directory-2014.php'

```
 function wpse_276403_output_scripts() {
   if (is_page_template('page-directory-2014.php')){
    ?>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #FCFCFC;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_276403_output_scripts' );
```

Thanks for all directions!

Comment: Does it work if you use `is_page_template('page-directory-2014.php')` or not? I'm not sure if the question is about working in multiple templates, or not working at all.

Comment: I tried what you are saying and it crashed the site. The code that works at the top of my questions works great but it is universal. What I would like is for the top to be applied to only 3 templates...(thanks BTW Jack - you've been really helpful these last 24 hours)

Comment: You're welcome :) I mean, the second code of yours. What happens when you use it? Wrong template? Error? Works? Or nothing at all?

Comment: My code crashes the entire theme/ WP installation. It might be b/c I am missing a { but I can't see where it is meant to go. What I am trying to do is apply this CSS to several unqiue templates in my theme

Comment: Well it might be because your conditional lacks a closing `}`. That's when indentation comes in handy.

Comment: Why are the php tags back-to-front?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean? The closing `}` belongs to `wpse_276403_output_scripts()`, so you have a conditional with `{` that has no closing tag (which should be placed right before `add_action()`). This is what is crashing your site.

Comment: Sorry - i meant - look at the third line down - there seems to be a rogue ?> and then further down there is the opening <?php... - why are these back-to-front? Thanks!

Comment: I meant the closing tag for the conditional. I've edited your code, copy it and check if it crashes the site now.

Comment: amazing - works perfect.