# Code I am placing in the wp_footer is going outside the entire HTML frame!

Tags: functions

I am trying to place Javascript within the wp_footer [(this is based on a previous question I asked here).](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276403/is-there-a-way-to-push-javascript-or-css-on-page-in-a-template-via-functions-p)

I would like for this Javascript to appear on the wp_footer of several templates but when I load it into functions.php here's what happens:

1. [GOOD] The Javascript is correctly placed where it is meant to be, but;
2. [BAD] The same Javascript is then oddly placed OUTSIDE of the closing < /html > tag which is odd.

Thanks for all direction.

```
 function jsdirectoryfilter() {
   if ( is_page_template( array('page-directory-2013.php','page-directory-2014.php','page-directory-2015.php','page-directory-2016.php','page-directory-2017.php','page-directory-2018.php'))){
    ?>
    <script>var options={valueNames:["name","location","category"]},userList=new List("users",options);</script>
    <?php
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'jsdirectoryfilter' );
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another instance of `wp_footer()` in some of your templates?

Comment: At the bottom of every template are the usual <?php get_footer(); ?> + <?php wp_footer(); ?> tags.... - is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. You should only have one of them in your template files. `get_footer()` should be in your template, and `wp_footer()` should be in your `footer.php`, before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Ah i see....i think that get_footer is the hook to read wp_footer for the template files - is that correct? Should ONLY template files have the get_footer? I need to read up on it!

Comment: Yes, if I see other themes (even the official WordPress ones) I can see that there is only get_footer

Comment: Yes exactly. You use `get_footer()` in your templates ( for example `page.php` ) and it calls `footer.php`, which you have your `wp_footer()` action hook in.